# Phonegap app cannot detect files inside subdirectory inside phonegaps root directory

Tags: cordova

I have a phonegap application which displays files in the app's folder previously created . i am using 
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(DIR_KM, {create: true,exclusive: false},onsuccess,onfailure); 
function . i am not able to access the files present in app's directorys sub directory . if i have a file in groups folder inside apps route folder i am not able to see it in the app , or this function does not give such files . is there any alternative